# Cannot set dynamic JSON in Protobuf schema of a Google Pub/Sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to associate a protobuf schema to a Google Pub/Sub topic,

This is an example of a message that will be received on the topic:

```json
{
    "event": {
        "original": "{ STRING JSON }"
    },
    "eventName": "STRING",
    "eventParams": {
        "DYNAMIC JSON"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2024-01-24 13:42:46.000",
    "eventUUID": "e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-2139684bb115",
    "sessionID": "65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-a4233ce92775",
    "userID": "ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-857ef141607a"
}
```

Note that the `eventParams` field is a dynamic JSON object, meaning I do not know beforehand the fields it will contain, though I know it will contain valid JSON object.

I have set Protobuf Schema to the following on Pub/Sub topic

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message Test {

    // `Struct` represents a structured data value, consisting of fields
    // which map to dynamically typed values. In some languages, `Struct`
    // might be supported by a native representation. For example, in
    // scripting languages like JS a struct is represented as an
    // object. The details of that representation are described together
    // with the proto support for the language.
    //
    // The JSON representation for `Struct` is JSON object.
    message Struct {
        // Unordered map of dynamically typed values.
        map<string, Value> fields = 1;
    }

    // `Value` represents a dynamically typed value which can be either
    // null, a number, a string, a boolean, a recursive struct value, or a
    // list of values. A producer of value is expected to set one of these
    // variants. Absence of any variant indicates an error.
    //
    // The JSON representation for `Value` is JSON value.
    message Value {
        // The kind of value.
        oneof kind {
            // Represents a null value.
            NullValue null_value = 1;
            // Represents a double value.
            double number_value = 2;
            // Represents a string value.
            string string_value = 3;
            // Represents a boolean value.
            bool bool_value = 4;
            // Represents a structured value.
            Struct struct_value = 5;
            // Represents a repeated `Value`.
            ListValue list_value = 6;
        }
    }

    // `NullValue` is a singleton enumeration to represent the null value for the
    // `Value` type union.
    //
    // The JSON representation for `NullValue` is JSON `null`.
    enum NullValue {
        // Null value.
        NULL_VALUE = 0;
    }

    // `ListValue` is a wrapper around a repeated field of values.
    //
    // The JSON representation for `ListValue` is JSON array.
    message ListValue {
        // Repeated field of dynamically typed values.
        repeated Value values = 1;
    }

    message Event {
        string original = 1;
    }

    optional Event event = 1;
    optional string eventName = 2;
    optional Struct eventParams = 3;
    optional string eventTimestamp = 4;
    optional string eventUUID = 5;
    optional string sessionID = 6;
    optional string userID = 7;
}
```

However, when I test with a message it doesn't work. I tested with the following JSON message

```json
{
    "event": {
        "original": "{ STRING }"
    },
    "eventName": "giftSent",
    "eventParams": {
        "a": 10600,
        "b": 20,
        "c": "WEB",
        "d": "35841161-f1b3-4947-a75f-057419c36988",
        "e": 1
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-01-24 13:42:46.000",
    "eventUUID": "e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-65461541",
    "sessionID": "65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-54654168",
    "userID": "ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-85645467a"
}
```

I get this error: `Invalid schema message: (eventParams) e: Cannot find field..`

Is this even possible to set up on Pub/Sub, are there any alternatives to set this up?

Answer (score 3):

Although Google's well-known types (WKTs) [Struct](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) and [Value](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#value) provides a mechanism to represent dynamic typed values like JSON as Protobuf schema, you can't trivially map this representation.

Here's your example using Go:

```golang
m := &pb.Test{}

j := `
{
    "event": {
        "original": "{ STRING }"
    },
    "eventName": "giftSent",
    "eventParams": {
        "a": 10600,
        "b": 20,
        "c": "WEB",
        "d": "35841161-f1b3-4947-a75f-057419c36988",
        "e": 1
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-01-24 13:42:46.000",
    "eventUUID": "e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-65461541",
    "sessionID": "65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-54654168",
    "userID": "ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-85645467a"
}`

if err := protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(j), m); err == nil {
    t.Error("expected unsuccessful marshal")
}
```

You **can't** unmarshal your JSON directly into your message type `Test` (here represented by `pb.Test` because `eventParams` contains a field `a` in the JSON but the Protobuf schema says this is part of a `Struct` (`map[string]Value`) and `Value` is `oneof` (but which one!?). In Go this must be explicitly:

```golang
m := &pb.Test{
    ...
    EventParams: &pb.Test_Struct{
        Fields: map[string]*pb.Test_Value{
            "a": {
                Kind: &pb.Test_Value_NumberValue{
                    NumberValue: 10600,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

There's a helper package [`structpb`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb) that includes a method [`NewValue`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb#NewValue) and this is [implemented](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/v1.32.0/types/known/structpb/struct.pb.go#L315) as a switch over all the possibilities but it still requires type annotations in Go:

```golang
m, err := structpb.NewValue(map[string]interface{}{
    "event": map[string]interface{}{
        "original": "{ STRING }",
    },
    "eventName": "giftSent",
    "eventParams": map[string]interface{}{
        "a": 10600,
        "b": 20,
        "c": "WEB",
        "d": "35841161-f1b3-4947-a75f-057419c36988",
        "e": 1,
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-01-24 13:42:46.000",
    "eventUUID":      "e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-65461541",
    "sessionID":      "65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-54654168",
    "userID":         "ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-85645467a",
})
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("+%v", m)

b, err := protojson.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal("expected successful marshal")
}

fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))
```

Here's the Protobuf message that the `structpb`'s `NewValue` constructs for your JSON message:

```
struct_value:{
  fields:{
    key:"event"
    value:{
      struct_value:{
        fields:{
          key:"original"
          value:{
            string_value:"{ STRING }"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"eventName"
    value:{
      string_value:"giftSent"
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"eventParams"
    value:{
      struct_value:{
        fields:{
          key:"a"
          value:{
            number_value:10600
          }
        }
        fields:{
          key:"b"
          value:{
            number_value:20
          }
        }
        fields:{
          key:"c"
          value:{
            string_value:"WEB"
          }
        }
        fields:{
          key:"d"
          value:{
            string_value:"35841161-f1b3-4947-a75f-057419c36988"
          }
        }
        fields:{
          key:"e"
          value:{
            number_value:1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"eventTimestamp"
    value:{
      string_value:"2018-01-24 13:42:46.000"
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"eventUUID"
    value:{
      string_value:"e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-65461541"
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"sessionID"
    value:{
      string_value:"65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-54654168"
    }
  }
  fields:{
    key:"userID"
    value:{
      string_value:"ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-85645467a"
    }
  }
}
```

This will marshal **correctly** as JSON:

```
{
    "event": {
        "original": "{ STRING }"
    },
    "eventName": "giftSent",
    "eventParams": {
        "a": 10600,
        "b": 20,
        "c": "WEB",
        "d": "35841161-f1b3-4947-a75f-057419c36988",
        "e": 1
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-01-24 13:42:46.000",
    "eventUUID": "e548a0eb-3dee-4fbc-9302-65461541",
    "sessionID": "65f9dd1c-3d76-4541-8296-54654168",
    "userID": "ae08f2df-7f54-472f-b3e0-85645467a"
}
```

So, yes, you can use `Struct` and `Value` to represent arbitrary JSON messages but you can't trivially validate these messages.

Comment: Thank you! yes Struct and Value are using `structpb` indeed under the hood as you can see [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) . But it seems like this is not supported on Google Pub/Sub (imports are also not supported)